# Is it possible to place the .bib file in another folder than the one where the .Rmd file is?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing a report and I will have to do an oral presentation on this. Therefore, I have a folder with a `.Rmd` file for the redaction, and another folder with another `.Rmd` file for the presentation.

Since I am going to use the same `.bib` file for these two `.Rmd` files, I was wondering if I could place the `.bib` "above" these two folders, such as:

```
Some folder
    |_ references.bib
    |_ redaction
           |_ redaction.Rmd
    |_ presentation
           |_ presentation.Rmd
```

Of course I could just copy-paste `references.bib` from `redaction` folder to `presentation` folder but I think the organization above would be cleaner.

This would require to specify the path for the `bib` file in the `YAML` of both `Rmd` files. Is it possible to do it?

Just a `YAML` for one of the `Rmd` file:

```
---
title: "A title"
author: "John Doe"
date: 02/04/2020
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: references.bib
---
```

**Edit:** A solution with the package [`here`](https://github.com/r-lib/here) is preferred, since I would like to avoid the use of absolute paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to specify a file path to the YAML header using double backslashes and no quotes

```
bibliography: C:\\Some folder\\references.bib
```

To use `here` instead of an absolute path simply specify r code

```
bibliography: "`r here::here('Some folder', 'references.bib')`"
```

Note you must use single quotes ('), rather than the normal r double quotes (") in the `here` arguments

Comment: This works with paths on Linux and MacOS too (with `//`). However, I was hoping  a solution with the package [`here`](https://github.com/r-lib/here) too avoid absolute paths. Do you know how to adapt it? I will add this requirement in my post